# d3 not showing added html elements

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am adding html elements via the following code. I see that html elements are added to the DOM but they are not visible.

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here?

The code is as follows

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("id", "canvas")
 .attr("width", 1000)
 .attr("height", 1000)
 ;

var data = [32, 57, 293, 900];

svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("cy", 90)
.attr("cx", String)
.attr("r", Math.sqrt);

var someData = [
{ "id": "0", "x": 100, "y": "200" },
{ "id": "1", "x": 200, "y": "200" },
{ "id": "2", "x": 300, "y": "200" }];

svg.selectAll("#canvas")
.data(someData)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "progress col-sm-1")
.append("div")
.attr("id", (d) => "prgrsBr" + d.id)
.attr("class", "progress-bar")
.attr("style", " background-color:blue; height: 150px");
```

Comment: It might be useful to have any `HTML` (particularly the part with the `id` of `canvas` and all `css`. There's a chance that setting `width:90%` isn't useful as `canvas` has a width of `0` or something weird like that

Comment: @EGC you are right. Here is the complete piece of code. I am setting the width to be greater than 0. Is it that we cannot add html elements inside svg that has a defined width and height?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`.attr("style", "width:90%; background-color:blue; height: 150px");`

Likely it is the height attribute missing (don't know what your CSS classes are.)

A [working JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/dexuran/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: What I am trying to do is add html to an existing svg element, I updated the code. Sorry for not doing this earlier.  The example you have adds an extra svg tag and adds the elements in it. Does that make sense?